# Why does the date disappear in SSRS report filter?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm working on a report in SSRS (Report Builder).

I created 2 parameters: 'date_from' and 'date_to' (and also added parameters to my query which I assigned to report parameters). Need to say that I used 'Convert' on a date becuase it was dat+time format in my dataset - that's why I converted it to date format.

[image]

Default value for 'date_from' is **=DateAdd("d",-1,Today())**, default for 'date_to' is just **=Today()**

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I run report everything is ok - proper data is returned based on dates but the problem occurs when I try to change dates in the filter above the report.

First of all - date doesn't show up in filter field when I choose it from the calendar, I can see just empty field as below (after setting default values for dates). Don't know, maybe this is how SSRS works:

[image]

Second - when I choose date from filter the date doesn't show up in date field (e.g. "Start date') but disappears. So I can't choose dates at all. Sometimes I can choose a date for 'Start date' but when I choose date for next field - 'End date' then date from 'Start date' disappears. And finally the result is as in the picture I pasted above - empty date fields.

So, summing up - I can set default values but when the report runs and I need to change dates it doesn't work at all.

Is it some kind of a bug? Or maybe I need to set other options or date formats?

Comment: can you try to deploy the report and see if the issue is still happening?

Comment: what if you made another dataset.. call it default dates.. and simply so  select convert(date,getdate()) as end_date
 , dateadd(day,-1, convert(date,getdate())) as start_date and then set your default from this dataset instead. what happens then?

Comment: I deployed my report on a web and everything works fine, strange